Symbolic solution of first-order quasilinear PDE
I tried to solve it using DSolve, but the program keeps running. Is there an issue with my settings, or is DSolve unable to solve this equation?
ClearAll["Global`*"];

pde = (y - b z[x, y]) D[z[x, y], x] - (x - a z[x, y]) D[z[x, y], y] ==
    b x - a y;
initialCondition = z[0, y] == y;


solution = 
 DSolve[{pde, initialCondition}, z[x, y], {x, y}, 
  Assumptions -> b != -1]


EDIT-20241203
The solution given in the textbook is as follows:
It is evident that
$a x+b y+z=c_1, \quad x^2+y^2+z^2=c_2$
are two independent first integrals of the characteristic equation
$\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{y-b z}=\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{-(x-a z)}=\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{b x-a y}$.
From the initial condition (x=0) and (z=y), we obtain
$ 2\left(\frac{c_1}{b+1}\right)^2 = c_2. $
Therefore, the solution is
$ x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2\left(\frac{ax+by+z}{b+1}\right)^2. $

Maple 2024 gives only for general solution: (Maple code){{z(x, y) = -a*x - b*y + C[1]}, {z(x, y) = (b*x*a + sqrt(-b^2*(a^2 + b^2 + 1))*a*y + b^2*y - b*x*sqrt(-b^2*(a^2 + b^2 + 1)))/(b*(a^2 + b^2))}, {z(x, y) = (b*x*a - sqrt(-b^2*(a^2 + b^2 + 1))*a*y + b^2*y + b*x*sqrt(-b^2*(a^2 + b^2 + 1)))/(b*(a^2 + b^2))}}

Thank you. My Maple code keeps running without any result. What is your Maple code? restart; pde := (y - b*z(x, y))*diff(z(x, y), x) - (x - a*z(x, y))*diff(z(x, y), y) = -a*y + b*x; initialCondition := z(0, y) = y; solution := pdsolve({pde, initialCondition}, z(x, y)); solution;   @Mariusz Iwaniuk

non linear pde's are hard to solve analytically, even first order pde's. Maybe in V 14.2 Mathematica could solve it?

It's well known that, though DSolve has been improving in recent versions, it's still far beyond perfect, and it's not that surprising to find differential equations that DSolve fails to handle. (See e.g. Nasser's test: https://12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/pde_in_cas.htm ) Of course, sometimes clever adjustions for options, etc. of DSolve helps, but your problem doesn't seem to be the case. (I sincerely hope I'm wrong. ) Still, we can do Mathematica aided deduction, which is slightly simpler than fully manual deduction in my view, is it of interest?

On Maple 2024.2 code: PDEtools:-PolynomialSolutions((y - b*z(x, y))*diff(z(x, y), x) - (x - a*z(x, y))*diff(z(x, y), y) = -a*y + b*x).

Thank you for your suggestion. Could you explain how to use Mathematica to assist in deduction? @ xzczd♦

Extend my comment to an answer. It's well known that, though DSolve has been improving in recent versions, it's still far beyond perfect, and it's not that surprising to find differential equations that DSolve fails to handle. (See e.g. Nasser's test for more info. ) Of course, sometimes clever adjustions for options, etc. of DSolve helps, but your problem doesn't seem to be the case. (I sincerely hope I'm wrong. )
Still, we can do Mathematica aided deduction, which is slightly simpler than fully manual deduction in my view. Since OP is interested in this, let me elaborate. We first find the characteristic equations, I'll use my characteristicEquations for the task:
(* Personally I suggest using With to simplify PDE coding. *)

pde = With[{z = z[x, y]}, 
           (y - b z) D[z, x] - (x - a z) D[z, y] == b x - a y]

(* Definition of characteristicEquations isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)

char = characteristicEquations[pde, "form" -> "standard", 
  "dummyVariable" -> t]

(* {z'[t] == b x[t] - a y[t], 
    x'[t] == y[t] - b z[t], 
    y'[t] == -x[t] + a z[t]} *)


Remark
At this point, we can in principle solve char with initial
conditions and eliminate t and C[_]s as mentioned in this
comment:
rule = DSolve[{char, x[0] == 0, y[0] == z[0]}, {x, y, z}, t][[1]];

termrule = E^(Sqrt[-1 - a^2 - b^2] t coef_.) :> term^coef;

sys = {x, y, z} == (Through[{x, y, z}[t]] /. rule) /. termrule // 
   Thread;

newsys = sys[[2 ;;]] /. First@Solve[sys[[1]], C[2]];

syslast = newsys[[1]] /. Solve[newsys[[2]], term] // Simplify;

And we can numerically verify the syslast is indeed correct:
ins = FindInstance[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 2 ((a x + b y + z)/(b + 1))^2, {a, b, x, y, z}, 
   Reals, 10];

Subtract @@@ syslast /. ins // N // Chop
(*
{{12.7539, 0}, {5.35655, 0}, {9.49641, 0}, 
 {0, 11.4351}, {0, -14.8715}, {-14.7562, 0}, 
 {9.95063, 0}, {0, -12.1022}, {14.4996, 0}, {-10.6687, 0}}
 *)

But syslast is too complicated, and there doesn't seem to be an
obvious way to simplify the syslast to the reference solution, so
let's go another way.

Then we need to find the first integrals.

It is evident that…

It takes me half an hour to notice this ¯\_(ツ)_/¯, but OK, I admit it becomes obvious once one notices it. The idea is as follows:

We need to eliminate the derivative terms from the characteristic equations (char).

Clearly the derivative terms cannot be directly eliminated.

So we need to eliminate non-derivative terms and integrate.


I'm not sure how general this method will be, but I believe it should be effective at least for textbook-level problems, because they are always well-made. For this specific problem, we just need to eliminate {x[t], y[t]} and {a, b} respectively and Integrate:
int = Integrate[Subtract @@ #, t] &;

firstintegral = {int@Eliminate[char, {x[t], y[t]}] == C[1], 
          int@Eliminate[char, {a, b}] == C[2]} // Simplify
(*
{C[1] == a x[t] + b y[t] + z[t], 
 2 C[2] == x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2} *)

Substitute the initial conditions into the first integrals (firstintegral):
sysc = firstintegral /. t -> t0 /. {x[t0] -> 0, y[t0] -> z[t0]}
(* {C[1] == z[t0] + b z[t0], 2 C[2] == 2 z[t0]^2} *)

For programming, it's not necessary to introduce t0. I make the substitution t -> t0 just to emphasize the $t$ is mathematically different here.
Eliminate the z[t0] term, we obtain the relation between $c_1$ (C[1]) and $c_2$ (C[2]):
eqc = Eliminate[sysc, z[t0]] // Simplify
(* C[1]^2 == (1 + b)^2 C[2] *)

Solve $c_1$ (C[1]) and $c_2$ (C[2]) from first integrals (firstintegral) and substitute them into eqc, we obtain the reference solution:
eqc /. Solve[firstintegral, {C[1], C[2]}][[1]]
(* (a x[t] + b y[t] + z[t])^2 == 1/2 (1 + b)^2 (x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 + z[t]^2) *)


If I try a purely numerical system with a set of continuous boundary conditions for a first order system in time t in the interval $0\le y \le 1$
DSolve[
   {(y - 3 z[t, y]) D[z[t, y], t] - (t - 2 z[t, y]) D[z[t, y], 
  y] == 2 t - 3 y, 
  z[0, y] == y, 
  z[t, 0] == 0, 
  z[t, 1] == 1}, 
  z[t, y], {t, y}]

Mathematica (14) returns the input unevaluated after 10 s. So  there seems to be no algorithm implemented for this quasilinear first order type.

See my EDIT. Thank you.
